# How do I variabilize x value in KERNELS==x condition of my udev rule?

Tags: networking, udev, adapter

For my udev rule, I want to read the value of `x` in condition `KERNELS=="x"` from a file or output of another command, is it possible?
If not, how do I make sure the rule is run for my specific net/device with known PCI?

Answer (score 0):

Instead for trying to load the condition value, leave it to your script to load that value and make decision if it should execute the required instructions.

You can know from which PCI by checking the environment variable `DEVPATH`

```
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eth0
```

or pass either `$devpath` or `%p` (path value) as argument to your script.